# List item text positioning in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML

```
<ul><li><p>With paragraph</p></li></ul>
<ul><li>Without paragraph</li></ul>
```

with the following CSS:

```
ul { list-style-position: inside; }
```

The text of the first list item is located below the list bullet, while for the second the text is located as usual:

```
*
With paragraph

* Without paragraph
```

What causes this positioning for the text, and how can I fix the CSS so that the text always becomes straight after the bullet?

A live demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8bncbnwg/).

Comment: `p` is a block level element that start from a new line. Make it `inline` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p>` tag is a block element which also has default `margin` and `padding`. So you need to "reset" those values and set `inline-block` like:

```css
ul { list-style-position: inside; }

ul p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul><li><p>With paragraph</p></li></ul>
<ul><li>Without paragraph</li></ul>
```

Comment: Why does `list-style-position: outside;` not have the same issue?

Comment: @Kaba cause `list-style-position` only says how the list gets styled. It can not change the style of elments inside the list which have different styles and which is the case here.

Comment: @Kaba if you use the inspector and `hover` over the `<p>` tag and toggle the `margin` and `padding` you will see exactly why and whats going on.

Comment: I see. With `outside`, the bullet is not part of the flow at all, which can be seen by adding a margin.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a p-tag is a block element. try using this:

```
ul li p { display : inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just display p as inline-block using CSS.